# Can't decode utf-8 string in python on os x terminal.app

Tags: python, macos, unicode, terminal

I have terminal.app set to accept utf-8 and in bash I can type unicode characters, copy and paste them, but if I start the python shell I can't and if I try to decode unicode I get errors:

```
>>> wtf = u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'.decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> wtf = u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368805/python-unicodedecodeerror-am-i-misunderstanding-encode/370199#370199) answer in a related question about encoding/decoding might be of help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think there is encode/decode confusion all over the place. You start with an unicode object:

```
u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'
```

This is an unicode object, the three characters are the unicode codepoints for "äöü". If you want to turn them into Utf-8, you have to **encode** them:

```
>>> u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'
```

The resulting six characters are the Utf-8 representation of "äöü".

If you call `decode(...)`, you try to interpret the characters as some encoding that still needs to be converted to unicode. Since it already is Unicode, this doesn't work. Your first call tries a Ascii to Unicode conversion, the second call a Utf-8 to Unicode conversion. Since `u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'` is neither valid Ascii nor valid Utf-8 these conversion attempts fail.

Further confusion might come from the fact that `'\xe4\xf6\xfc'` is also the Latin1/ISO-8859-1 encoding of "äöü". If you write a normal python string (without the leading "u" that marks it as unicode), you can convert it to an unicode object with `decode('latin1')`:

```
>>> '\xe4\xf6\xfc'.decode('latin1')
u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'
```

Comment: aha. This finally makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have encoding and decoding backwards. You encode Unicode into a byte stream, and decode the byte stream into Unicode.

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Dec  6 2008, 16:42:21) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5370)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> wtf = u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'
>>> wtf
u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'
>>> print wtf
äöü
>>> wtf.encode('UTF-8')
'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'
>>> print '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'.decode('utf-8')
äöü
```

Comment: Um. UTF-8 is an already encoded byte stream, so, while not backwards, you got it sideways at least :) Perhaps you meant Unicode instead of UTF-8. I'll edit your post and let you decide.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> wtf = '\xe4\xf6\xfc'
>>> wtf
'\xe4\xf6\xfc'
>>> print wtf
���
>>> print wtf.decode("latin-1")
äöü
>>> wtf_unicode = unicode(wtf.decode("latin-1"))
>>> wtf_unicode
u'\xe4\xf6\xfc'
>>> print wtf_unicode
äöü
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Unicode strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings) section of the introductory tutorial explains it well :

> To convert a Unicode string into an 8-bit string using a specific encoding, Unicode objects provide an encode() method that takes one argument, the name of the encoding. Lowercase names for encodings are preferred.
>
> ```
> >>> u"äöü".encode('utf-8')
> '\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc'
> ```

Comment: aren't you decoding characters then in your last line?

Comment: Yep, I've removed my fatigued-wrongness, the unicode strings section explains it better than I can..