# Django Mandrill email encoding

Tags: python, django, pdf, mandrill, pisa

**Edit**. Found the solution: it seems the pdf document has to be base64 encoded. Editing the async view as such works:

```
import base64
result = export_pdf(request)
encoded = base64.b64encode(result.getvalue())
email = mandrill.Mandrill(settings.MANDRILL_API_KEY)
email.messages.send_template(mandrill_template, [], {'to':[{'email':user.email}], 'subject':subject, 'text':message, attachments':[{'type':'application/pdf', 'name':'pdf file', 'content':encoded}] })
```

**end of edit**

I have a problem sending a pdf document created with xhtml2pdf/pisa as a attachement in Mandrill.
The application work as follows: a content_view calls an `async_view` which

1. generates the pdf (by calling an export_pdf function) and
2. sends the email with attachment.

The pdf document seems valid (if I modify the `async_view` to `HttpResponse` the pdf instead of sending it, I see a valid pdf document). 
But sending it to Mandrill returns an encoding error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position
>   11: invalid start byte.

I tried to solve it as mentionned here ([Python: Sanitize a string for unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224427/python-sanitize-a-string-for-unicode)). In this case, no error is raised anymore, but the pdf I get as email attachement is considered as 'text/plain' and not readable.
Thank you for your help!

async_view

```
pdf_doc = export_pdf(request).getvalue() # .decode("windows-1252").encode("utf-8", 'ignore') would not raise an error but would be considered as plain text
email = mandrill.Mandrill(settings.MANDRILL_API_KEY)
email.messages.send_template(mandrill_template, [], {'to':[{'email':user.email}], 'subject':subject, 'text':message, attachments':[{'type':'application/pdf', 'name':'pdf file', 'content':pdf_doc}] })

# return HttpResponse(pdf_doc,  mimetype='application/pdf') would return a well formatted pdf
```

export_pdf function

```
def export_pdf(request):

    html  = render_to_string('pdf.html', { 'pagesize' : 'A4', }, context_instance=RequestContext(request,{
                'text': text,
            },))
    result = cStringIO.StringIO()       
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html), dest=result, encoding='UTF-8')
    if not pdf.err:
        return result
    else:
        return None
```

the interresting part of the traceback is

```
(...)
File "/home/raphael/Applications/Virtualenvs/apps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mandrill.py", line 1476, in send_template
    return self.master.call('messages/send-template', _params)
File "/home/raphael/Applications/Virtualenvs/apps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mandrill.py", line 137, in call
    params = json.dumps(params)
File "/home/raphael/Applications/Virtualenvs/apps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 354, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "/home/raphael/Applications/Virtualenvs/apps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 262, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/home/raphael/Applications/Virtualenvs/apps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 340, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Comment: If you've found the answer yourself, it's best to post it as an answer and accept it. This way, your question will be marked as answered and may be referenced in the future if another similar question pops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution: it seems the pdf document has to be base64 encoded. Editing the async view as such works:

```
import base64
result = export_pdf(request)
encoded = base64.b64encode(result.getvalue())
email = mandrill.Mandrill(settings.MANDRILL_API_KEY)
email.messages.send_template(mandrill_template, [], {'to':[{'email':user.email}], 'subject':subject, 'text':message, attachments':[{'type':'application/pdf', 'name':'pdf file', 'content':encoded}] })
```