# Python - Turning a string into a list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to turn this string into a list:

```
f = open( "animals.txt", "r")
g = f.read()
g1 = g.split(",")
print g1 # list of words
```

I'm getting:

```
['\x93SHEEP\x94', '\x94TIGER\x94', '\x94LION\x94', '\x94DEER\x94',
'\x94PIG\x94', '\x94DOG\x94', '\x94CAT\x94', '\x94SHARK\x94',
'\x94RAT\x94', '\x94EEL\x94']
```

What I want is:

```
['SHEEP', 'TIGER', 'LION', 'DEER', 'PIG', 'DOG', 'CAT', 'SHARK', 'RAT', 'EEL']
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post the content of animals.txt?  Maybe a hexdump, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `encode('ascii','ignore')` to remove unicodes , but note that first you need to clarify for python that your strings are unicode you can do it with `decode('unicode_escape')` :

```
>>> l
['\x93SHEEP\x94', '\x94TIGER\x94', '\x94LION\x94', '\x94DEER\x94', '\x94PIG\x94', '\x94DOG\x94', '\x94CAT\x94', '\x94SHARK\x94', '\x94RAT\x94', '\x94EEL\x94']
>>> [i.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore') for i in l]
['SHEEP', 'TIGER', 'LION', 'DEER', 'PIG', 'DOG', 'CAT', 'SHARK', 'RAT', 'EEL']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this on the top of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your strings with:

```
g.decode("unicode-escape")
```

or:

```
for i in range(0,len(g1)):
    g1[i] = g1[i].decode("unicode-escape")
```

This is assuming g1 is the array containing the strings and g is the variable containing the whole file as a string.

I got my answer from:

[Python: Sanitize a string for unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224427/python-sanitize-a-string-for-unicode)