# Python: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position

Tags: python, unicode

I am getting this error:

```
File "run.py", line 37, in <module>
 print str1
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 24-29: ordinal not in range(256)
```

When trying to simply print some Japanese text. Actually it seems the string looks like this:

> \u5149\u66dc\u65e5\u3067\u30e9\u30c6 \u30d4\u30af\u30b7\u30fc\u4e71\u7372\u884c\u304d\u307e\u3059 \u5e0c\u671b\u8005\u52df\u96c6\u4e2d\u3067\u3059\uff3e\uff3e

Which comes in from a JSON file. How can I print this?

Code:

```
url = "http://www.blah.com/json"
try:
  result = simplejson.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
except IOError:
  print "Cannot open URL"
  data = "error"

for msg in result["msg"]:
  str1 = msg["character"] + " : " + msg["message"]
  print str1
```

repr(str1) is

```
u'Anys : \u5149\u66dc\u65e5\u3067\u30e9\u30c6 \u30d4\u30af\u30b7\u30fc\u4e71\u7372\u884c\u304d\u307e\u3059 \u5e0c\u671b\u8005\u52df\u96c6\u4e2d\u3067\u3059\uff3e\uff3e'
```

print(sys.stdout.encoding) is

```
ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: What does your code look like? What encoding is your text in? Latin-1, as the name would imply, can't encode Japanese characters.

Comment: Please post `repr(str1)`, and `print(sys.stdout.encoding)`

Comment: What system is this running on? It's detecting sys.stdout as latin-1 encoded, and you can't write Japanese characters in Latin 1.

Comment: I've added the full code, sorry about that.

Comment: unutbu: I edited those into my post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942888/unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that you see is because you terminal use latin-1 as encoding, as a side note you can check the encoding of your terminal (assuming that it's your stdout) by doing in your shell:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding"
```

And now for printing in UTF-8 you should encode your string to utf-8 manually like this:

```
s = u"\u5149\u66dc\u65e5\u3067\u30e9\u30c6 \u30d4\u30af\u30b7\u30fc\u4e71\u7372\u884c\u304d\u307e\u3059 \u5e0c\u671b\u8005\u52df\u96c6\u4e2d\u3067\u3059\uff3e\uff3e"
print s.encode('utf-8')
#Output: 光曜日でラテ ピクシー乱獲行きます 希望者募集中です＾＾
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. For some reason I was trying a different .encode() line that someone said to do elsewhere and it was generating another error.

Comment: I do not believe this is the correct answer.  You should not manually encode to UTF-8.  You should set your output stream encoding to that.

Comment: The above (`print`ing bytes) will work on Unix if your terminal character encoding is UTF-8.  But as tchrist points out, it is not a general solution.  On Windows, the console is character based, not byte based.  Alternatively try `sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('UTF-8')(sys.stdout)` then simply `print s`.

Comment: @wberry, @tchrist : AFAIK window console only display 256 characters (cp437) and setting the stdout encoding to `UTF8` is not recommended (see: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails). AFAIK there is no general solution for the print encoding failures in python 2 i think the solution will vary depending on what you're doing, if you want to log use the `logging` module instead of print, if you want just to debug your program i will go with my solution (encode with the right encoding when needed), think can also start to be ugly when using subprocess or threads in your program ...

Comment: There's no general solution for the Windows console even in Python 3. Limitations in the Windows implementation of the C stdio library and the console itself prevent reliable Unicode output. This affects many other languages and tools too.