# Python MySQL encoding Error: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have been stuck for a while with a `UnicodeEncodeError` in Python.

Here is what I am doing:

1. I create a Dataframe as a result of a various analysis. In total, the dataframe has 30 columns with multiple types of values (`int`,`string`,`datetime`,etc).
2. I create an SSH connection to a remote instance in Azure where I have installed MySQL. I create the connection using `SQLAlchemy`.
3. I run the `df.to_sql` command and get the following error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2013'
>   in position 8: ordinal not in range(256)

I tried doing this but it didn't seem to work.

`engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@host:%s/db?charset=utf8' % server.local_bind_port)`

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290206/python-unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character) that I can use `u.encode('latin-1', 'replace')`. But would I need to perform that and go through every `String` column and encode it? Or is there something else that I can do?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @pshep123 - In Azure I am using Python 2.7.12 - In my local PC 2.7.13 Anaconda 4.4.0

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I'm not going to be able to help you, but I've been running into unicode issues myself and through my recent research, have come to realize that python 3 and python 2 handle text formatting differently and thus it's important for those more knowledgeable than I to know which version.  Here is some reading in the meantime: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html, might help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I came up with.

I created a function that encoded the different characters in my data.

```
def custom_encoder(x):
    #Check if the value is Unicode
    if type(x)==type(u''):
        return x.encode('utf8','ignore')
    else:
        return x
```

The I looped through all the columns and encoded all the values. After this, MySQL allowed the data to be written.