# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' when reading a textfile

Tags: python

I am new to reading textfiles.  i run the following code:

```
with open('sometext.txt', 'rb') as xy: txt = xy.read().decode('utf-8')
```

i get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201e' in position 137: ordinal not in range(256)
```

i already tried to play around with encoding and decoding. but without success. the text in the file is german, may the error depends on that. thanks for help

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290206/python-unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290206/python-unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character)