# Decoding with 'utf-8' but error show an Unicode Encode Error?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, decoding

My Python **2.x** script trys to download a web page including Chinese words. It's encoded in UTF-8. By urllib.openurl(url), I get content in type *str*, so I decode content with UTF-8. It throws Unicode**Encode**Error. I googled a lot of posts like [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942888/unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character), but they don't work for me. Am I misunderstand something?

My code is:

```
import urllib
import httplib
def get_html_content(url):
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    print type(html)
    return html


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://weekly.manong.io/issues/58'
    html = get_html_content(url)
    print html.decode('utf-8')
```

Error message:

```
<type 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\src\infra.py", line 32, in <module>
    print html.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 44: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 1.6s]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) converts arguments to `str` objects. Encoding it manually will prevent to encode it with ascii:

```
import sys

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://weekly.manong.io/issues/58'
    html = get_html_content(url)
    print html.decode('utf-8').encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'ignore')
```

Replace `sys.stdout.encoding` with encoding of your terminal unless it print correctly.

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you can use [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environmental variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) without encoding in the source code:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8:ignore python program.py
```

Comment: `print unicode_string` is the preferable way. Do not hardcode the encoding of your environment inside your script. [Use `PYTHONIOENCODING` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28011696/4279)

Comment: *"print implicitly call str"* is oversimplification e.g., it does not explain why the first command in my answer works (it prints non-ascii character to the terminal).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Thank you for comments. I edited the sentence according to you.

Comment: what *"default encoding"* do you mean? Is it `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`, `locale.getpreferredencoding(True)`, `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`? `sys.stdout.encoding` may be `None` (try the second command in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If the standard output is redirected to a pipe then Python 2 fails to use your locale encoding:

```
⟫ python -c'print u"\u201c"' # no redirection -- works
“
⟫ python -c'print u"\u201c"' | cat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To fix it; you could specify `PYTHONEIOENCODING` environment variable e.g., in bash:

```
⟫ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -c'print u"\u201c"' | cat
“
```

On Windows, you need to set the envvar using a different syntax.

If your Windows console doesn't support utf-8 (it matters only for the first command where there is no redirection) then you could try to print Unicode directly using Win32 API calls like [`win-unicode-console`](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) does. See [windows console doesn't print or input Unicode](http://bugs.python.org/issue1602).