# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 56-58: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, django, utf-8

I get the bellow error, when I request for a Chinese character name image:

```
line 507, in handle_one_response
    result = self.application(self.environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line 49, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 156, in __call__
    request = self.request_class(environ)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 80, in __init__
    path_info = get_path_info(environ)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 175, in get_path_info
    path_info = get_bytes_from_wsgi(environ, 'PATH_INFO', '/')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 224, in get_bytes_from_wsgi
    return value.encode(ISO_8859_1) if six.PY3 else value
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 56-58: ordinal not in range(256)
```

the image url is:

[http://localhost:8000/images/qiyun_admin_websitemanage/bannerreconmend/服务器.png](http://localhost:8000/images/qiyun_admin_websitemanage/bannerreconmend/%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1%E5%99%A8.png)

(and the url is exists in my database with the Chinese character)

and I searched the SO, found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12064483/7693832).

it says

```
db.set_character_set('utf8')
dbc.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
dbc.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
dbc.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
```

In my Django project, I can not find the place to add those code.

only the configuration codes there in my `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_mine',
        'USER':'root',
        'PASSWORD':'root',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

So, how to solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried to put # -*- coding: utf8 -*- at first line of code?

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the database. And neither would adding a coding line in @Shin-BangTsai; that is only for *literal characters* in the module code itself.

Comment: @Shin-BangTsai Do you mean in the `settings.py`? I have the `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the first line of `settings.py`, but not work.

Comment: if you make the get request in views.py add this line in views.py

Comment: @Shin-BangTsai I did, bro but not work for me.

Comment: I guess django does not accept Chinese character in url, maybe the best way to solve this is loop through all of your image files and rename them with urllib.parse.quote function as @snakecharmerb answered

Answer (score 1):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/5320906) states, the set of valid characters in urls is

`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`.`

Other characters should be quoted to be sure that they will be handled correctly.  You can quote them using the `urllib.parse.quote` function.

```
>>> filename = '服务器.png'
>>> quoted_filename = urllib.parse.quote(filename)
>>> print(quoted_filename)
%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1%E5%99%A8.png
```

and use the quoted version when constructing your urls.

Comment: do you mean in the frontend request to quote ?