# write list in pdf file using python

Tags: python, pdf, writefile

[image]I am trying to write list of strings in pdf file using below script.

```
pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format='letter')
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)

for i in data:
    pdf.write(5,str(i))
    pdf.ln()
pdf.output("testings.pdf")
```

But, I am getting error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 1548: ordinal not in range(256)
```

data contain results in string format
Can anyone please help me to know how to write results in pdf file, I want to write each string in data list separate page.

Above is data screenshot
The length is huge so not inserting all records but list contain text data only

Comment: Is data a list of numbers? Then you should first convert it to string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942888/unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character)

Comment: @toti08, Data a list text , there are total  strings which I am trying to write in PDF file

Comment: Could you post your `data` variable?

Comment: @toti08, I have inserted screenshot of data which i am trying to write in PDF

Comment: Thanks! I think your problem lays in the double quote character, which has code `201c`, you should better use utf-8 coding.

Comment: @toti08, It worked thank you so much. I changed below line in fpdf.py file."p = self.pages[n].encode("utf-8") if PY3K else self.pages[n]" But now I want each string in separate page in PDF file

Answer (score 0):

This is because MySQLdb normally tries to encode everythin to latin-1. This can be fixed by executing the following commands right after you've etablished the connection:
I also have the same problem Python MySQLdb module. Since MySQL will let you store just about any binary data you want in a text field regardless of character set, I found my solution here
[Link](https://dasprids.de/blog/2007/12/17/python-mysqldb-and-utf-8/)