# AWS SAM throws UnicodeEncodeError when invoking NodeJS 12.x lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have a Lambda@Edge function that will fire when a user connects to my website to perform authentication, which is controlled by a CloudFront distribution I've setup for my website.

I want to develop this code locally so I setup a dummy HelloWorld project using AWS SAM CLI and replaced its source code with my lambda@edge function. I've also created a JSON file that represents the event that will be passed to my lambda function during `sam local` invocation or when I run tests, placed under the "event" directory under my project folder.

I am able to run unit tests via `npm run test` and have it both fail and pass so I know the code base is working. However, when I try to invoke it using `sam local invoke -e events/sample_event.json`, I get the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in
> position 0: Body ('\ufeff') is not valid Latin-1. Use
> body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

The traceback shows this error was emitted from a Python 3 HTTP client:
`/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py`

Does anyone know why this encoding error is being emitted? I've used converters to ensure the contents of the event JSON file conform to utf-8 format. I can't understand why this is happening and what I should do to remedy it. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942888/unicodeencodeerror-latin-1-codec-cant-encode-character)  (you may have bad quotation marks)

Comment: You are right I am using double quotes. However, this is done because JSON uses double quotes for key and string values. So I don't think I can switch it to single quotes. I got it working by creating a completely new SAM project and using the "hello world" template then modifying its contents as it comes with an example event JSON file.

Comment: So yea,  this question is likely a dupe. However, change your **Right & left double quotation marks** to **neutral quotation marks** and you will be fine. more info here: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html