# encoding problem with pgsql/python?

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding

I retrieved a bunch of text records from my postgresql database and intend to preprocess these text documents before analyzing them.

I want to tokenize the documents but ran into some problem during tokenizing

```
    #some other bunch of regex replacements
    #toToken is the text string    
    toTokens = self.regexClitics1.sub(" \\1",toTokens)                   
    toTokens = self.regexClitics2.sub(" \\1 \\2",toTokens)

    toTokens = str.strip(toTokens)
```

The error is `TypeError: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'` I'm curious, why does this error occurs, when the encoding of the database is UTF-8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `toTokens.strip()`. No need of str module.

There are 2 string types in Python, str and unicode. Look at [this](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) for an explanation.

Comment: +1.  A shorter explanation can be found on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545661/unicodedecodeerror-when-redirecting-to-file/4546129#4546129 (shameless plug). :)

Comment: does that means that the strings I get from my queries are unicode? Why is that so?

Comment: @amateur It seems so. It's strange, because AFAIK psycopg returns str objects unless instructed to do otherwise, but can't know without more information about your setup.