# Python string/list with £ symbols failing writing to file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, character-encoding

I am having issues writing data to a file due to `£` signs being in my string/list.

For example in my code below, `x` is created by a series of appends from various regex searchs, matches, subs and generic trims/splits.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
x = [u'Loc ', u'352', '1', '51', '3D2', u'Student Total \xa3540.00', u'Discount \xa235.00', '\n', u'Rec ', u'352', '2', '51', '5S1', u'Student Total \xa3540.00', u'Discount \xa235.00', '\n']
with open('test.txt','w') as dfile:
    dfile.write('\n'.join(x)) # UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 71: ordinal not in range(128)
    dfile.write(x) # TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I am trying to write x to file so it appears like:

```
Loc
352
1
51
3D2
Student Total £3540.00
Discount £235.00

Rec
352
2
51
5S1
Student Total £3540.00
Discount £235.00
```

Anyone know how I can do what I am trying to achieve?

**EDIT**

I now can't get it to compare and if it's different then save...

```
with open('test.txt','r') as dfile:
    dfiler = dfile.read()
    dfiler = dfiler.decode("UTF-8")
    if dfiler == x:
        print "same, no need to save"
    else:            
        with open('test.txt','w') as result_end_datafile:
            dfile.write('\n'.join(x).encode("UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Read this: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: The edit is fairly distinct from the original question. Perhaps you could open a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the unicode string before writing:

```
dfile.write('\n'.join(x).encode("UTF-8"))
```

Alternatively, you use use [codecs.`open()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) in Python 2.x, thus passing the encoding as the argument while opening file:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('test.txt', 'w', encoding="UTF-8") as dfile:
    dfile.write('\n'.join(x))
```

---

**Related:**

- [UnicodeDecodeError when redirecting to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4545661/1679863)

Comment: Works good, however the `£` on the discount one comes out as: ¢35.00 as it's picking up the 2 as part of the ascii...

Comment: I started recommending `io.open()` instead of `codecs.open()` as that'll continue to work the same on Python 3. The API is much the same to `codecs.open()` but offers more options, including newline handling.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. Oh! Will take a look at it. Didn't knew about that.

Comment: @Hyflex - you've mistyped your input strings in the `x` list. `\xa3` is the british currency symbol £, `\xa2` is the the cents symbol ¢.

Comment: Thank you ever so much guys, I've got another problem now again because of these. I'll edit the main post.