# Error writing a text file Python

Tags: python, text, fwrite

Hi i'm running a program to parse a table from a HTML address. It all works fine and I'm able to print the data i'm extracting. But when i try to write a txt file with the data I get the error msg below. Anyone can help me, please? don't know what I'm missing.

```
myfile.write(tds[0].text+ ","+ tds[4].text+ ","+ tds[7].text+ ","+ tds[12].text+ ","+ tds[14].text+ ","+ tds[17].text)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "teste.py", line 14, in <module>
    myfile.write(tds[0].text+ ","+ tds[4].text+ ","+ tds[7].text+ ","+ tds[12].text+ ","+ tds[14].text+ ","+ tds[17].text.encode('utf8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing text types.  You use "," and the *.text methods of defining the overall string you hope to write into the file.  Therefore you are mixing encoding.  While a more elegant solution exists to your problem, the quick and dirty way to achieve this may be to use:

```
str(tds[*])
```

vice

```
tds[*].text()
```

Comment: when i use str(tds[*]) the writing works but it writes the whole td tag not just the info. like this :<td class="raceline">31.21¬†</td>

Comment: sorry, I missed that part of your question.  It now sounds like you are talking about how do you parse html or xml.  Have you used beautiful soup before:http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html

Comment: i'm able to parse and i have writen a file in another table parsing that i did. i'm doing the same that  did before but this time is not working

Answer (score 0):

To understand why your code breaks check out this [anwser about the basics of Python and Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546129/2898712).

In your case it will probably help to use `tds[*].text.decode("ecoding of original HTML")`