# Django management command raises UnicodeEncodeError only when redirecting output to file

Tags: python, linux, django, shell, stdout

I have built a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) that prints out some stuff on stdout (using `print`). All works fine, but...

When I try to redirect the output to a file, using

```
./manage.py my_command > a_file.txt
```

I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

No traceback, just that.

I tried `./manage.py my_command | less` just for the fun of it, and it showed some output, presumably lines before first non-ASCII char was encountered. Output has some UTF-8 chars, no way around that.

Same error happens on Mac laptop and on Red Hat Linux server. Using Python 2.7.9

What's happening here, and how can I dump the info to a file?

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick with my previous comment. But I think this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4546129/870769) could be of help. It suggests configuring the `PYTHONIOENCODING` env variable when redirecting or piping. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @sthzg Oh yeah! interstingly enough, `print sys.stdout.encoding` showed `UTF-8`, but after defining `$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` the problem is no more. Go figure...

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError when redirecting to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545661/unicodedecodeerror-when-redirecting-to-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the standard output of the script with UTF-8 encoded output :

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
```

Or you can encode your strings before printing them:

```
print string_containing_unicode.encode('utf-8')
```