# conversion of html code into respective diacritic symbol/alphabet

Tags: python, html, diacritics

I have a HTML file containing words like `<i>r&#363;pa</i>`.
How to convert it into `rūpa`(r**ū**pa)?

Is there any way to convert it?

Also i get to know that these are the html representation of extended binary code,(correct me if i am wrong).

python is preferred, but solution in any language is appreciated.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545661/unicodedecodeerror-when-redirecting-to-file/4546129#4546129