# Python chokes on non-ascii characters when output to a UNIX pipeline

Tags: python, unix, pipe

Here is the reduced content of my script:

```
print u"w\xa0p"
```

which will print "w" character, followed by a nonbreaking space, then "p" to the TTY. However when this script is passed on to a pipeline, e.g.

```
python script.py | cat
```

(the exact command on the right of the pipeline is not important, as long as the python command is passed onto a UNIX pipeline), python will complain with this kind of error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can somebody explain why this error happened, and how to mitigate it? Apparently there is a different codec for  I guess we could use [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) package to mitigate the issue at the cost of character precision; but I wonder if we can force python to print the utf-8 characters out anyway if the output pipeline is in use.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this question, is the same problem you have there [UnicodeDecodeError when redirecting to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545661/unicodedecodeerror-when-redirecting-to-file)

You should read all the answer from [EOL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42973/eol) to understand the problem, but if you are in a rush, here is the important part of the code you need to use:

```
import codecs
import locale
import sys

# Wrap sys.stdout into a StreamWriter to allow writing unicode.
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(locale.getpreferredencoding())(sys.stdout)

uni = u"w\xa0p"
print uni
```