# Error occurs when trying to redirect Python UTF-8 stdout to a file on Windows

Tags: python, windows, powershell

When I try to redirect a UTF-8 stdout in Powershell by running `python3 .\test.py > test.txt`, error occurs :

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>

The code in `test.py` are as following and that is encoded by UTF-8.

```
print("\u2714")
```

The code is uploaded here.
https://github.com/lingsongfeng/pytest

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example code?

Comment: @Rivers OK, I uploaded it on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/lingsongfeng/pytest

Comment: Please post it here (edit your answer). Could you take some time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Rivers Thank you to mention that. I have already edited my question.

Comment: Ok. but there is no code in your question.

Comment: @Rivers There is only one line of code in the file, so as in this question. That is a call of ```print``` function. I am not sure whether you could see the code but I can see that...

Comment: You should use `'\u2714'` so that there's no chance of the encoding of your source file making a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When redirecting I/O Python uses a default encoding for Windows (`cp1252` for US Windows), but will look to an environment variable if you want to override it:

```
C:\> set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
C:\> test.py > out.txt
```

Recently, `set PYTHONUTF8=1` will also make Python default to UTF-8 for files and I/O redirection.

Comment: I tried modify the environment variable but it doesn't work. But I found ```sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')``` can help. After adding this line, the redirection can work. However, the output file is UTF-16 LE format with FF FE at the beginning when I hexdumped it.

Comment: It works. How did you test it? I set in cmd window, tested, then started power shell and tested again.

Comment: Oh that's my fault. I directly copied the CMD set command into Powershell without knowing setting environment variable in pwsh is different... But there is still problem. The output file is formatted by UTF-16 LE, not UTF-8. Neither vscode nor notepad display non ASCII characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in python official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html):

> On Windows, UTF-8 is used for the console device. Non-character
> devices such as disk files and pipes use the system locale encoding
> (i.e. the ANSI codepage). Non-console character devices such as NUL
> (i.e. where isatty() returns True) use the value of the console input
> and output codepages at startup, respectively for stdin and
> stdout/stderr. This defaults to the system locale encoding if the
> process is not initially attached to a console.
>
> The special behaviour of the console can be overridden by setting the
> environment variable PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO before starting Python.
> In that case, the console codepages are used as for any other
> character device.
>
> Under all platforms, you can override the character encoding by
> setting the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable before starting
> Python or by using the new -X utf8 command line option and PYTHONUTF8
> environment variable. However, for the Windows console, this only
> applies when PYTHONLEGACYWINDOWSSTDIO is also set.

It says that python use UTF-8 for console printing but ANSI for pipes.And IO redirection in powershell is actually a kind of pipes.So some utf-8 characters can't be encoded by ANSI,which causes the error.
There are three solutions:

by environment

```
$env:PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"
```

by hard code

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

by command

```
python -X utf8 test.py
```