# how to convert 8-bit hebrew to utf-8 in python

Tags: python, utf-8

I have hebrew data such that \xe0 is the hebrew aleph,
and wish to convert it into utf-8

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368805/python-unicodedecodeerror-am-i-misunderstanding-encode/370199#370199) answer. Also, note that your strings are most probably encoded as `cp1255` (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) ), not `iso8859-8`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general in Python, if you have a byte string you need to use decode first to convert it to the internal representation, afterwards you can encode it to UTF-8.  Of course, you need to know the coding of `\xe0` for this to work (I assume your character is encoded using ISO-8859-8):

```
'\xe0'.decode('iso-8859-8').encode('utf-8')
```

**EDIT:**
A side note:

Make sure to use the internal representation in your program as long as possible.  In general: decode first (on input), encode last (on output).

Comment: Encoding is probably iso-8859-8, if not Windows-1255.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "decode" call to transform it in unicode

```
y = x.decode('iso8859-8')
```

where `x` is your 8-bit string and `y` is the unicode string
then you can convert it to utf-8 using the `encode` call

```
z = y.encode('utf-8')
```