# How do you store a non-ASCII character in Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, ascii

I've tried no less then 5 different "solutions" and i cant get it to work, please help.

This is the error

```
  'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 636, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/elmovieplace/1.350096827241428223/script/pftv.py", line 114, in post
    movie.put()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 984, in put
    return datastore.Put(self._entity, config=config)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 455, in Put
    return _GetConnection().async_put(config, entities, extra_hook).get_result()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1219, in async_put
    for pbs in pbsgen:
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1070, in __generate_pb_lists
    pb = value_to_pb(value)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 239, in entity_to_pb
    return entity._ToPb()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 841, in _ToPb
    properties = datastore_types.ToPropertyPb(name, values)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 1672, in ToPropertyPb
    pbvalue = pack_prop(name, v, pb.mutable_value())
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 1485, in PackString
    pbvalue.set_stringvalue(unicode(value).encode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the part of the code that's giving me problems.

```
if imdbValues[5] == 'N/A':
    movie.diector = ''
else:
    movie.director = imdbValues[5]

...

movie.put()
```

In this case `imdbValues[5]` is equal to `Claudio FÃ¤h`

Comment: You should read this: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python . You need to make sure you are clear on when you are dealing with bytes, when you are dealing with strings, and what encoding you should be using to convert between the two. Encoding/Decoding errors such as you see usually occur because of misunderstandings about string handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is raised by this line of code:

```
pbvalue.set_stringvalue(unicode(value).encode('utf-8'))
```

When you pass a value to `movie.director` , that value is first converted in unicode with:

```
unicode(value)
```

then it is encoded with `encode('utf-8')`.

The `unicode()` function tipically uses ASCII as default decode encoding; it means that you are safe only passing these kind of values:

1. A unicode string
2. A 8 bit string

Your code is probably passing a byte string with some encoding that the `unicode(value)` fails to decode in ASCII.

*Recommendation:*
if you are dealing with byte strings, **you MUST know their encoding** or your program will suffer this kind of encoding/decoding problem.

*How to fix it:*
discover the encoding used in the byte strings you are dealing with (utf-8?) and convert them in unicode strings.
If, for example, `imdbValues` is a list returned by some fancy *Imdb python libraries* that contains utf-8 encoded byte strings, you should convert them using:

```
 movie.director = imdbValues[5].decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: also if you don't mind answering another question, is there a way to do this with lists.

Comment: @Jon try with a list comprehension: `unicode_list = [item.decode('utf-8') for item in imdbValues]`

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing. I have an app engine assignment name='全部'. The string is utf-8 encoded. Tried decode(utf-8) but still got the same error "'ascii' codec can't decode byte"

Answer (score 2):

You should start using `unicode` for your textual data.

Wherever you get your data, they are Unicode characters encoded as bytes. The encoding could be `UTF-8`, or `UTF-16`, or `Windows-1252`, or `ISO-8859-1` or many other encodings. If the data exist on your system, you know the encoding. If they came from a web page, the encoding is included in the response headers, and often in the beginning of the page. Using that encoding, `.decode` to the very useful `unicode` Python object and use that in your code.

Decode on input, encode (if necessary) on output. It's not necessary to encode before using the data with App Engine.

PS [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368805/) answer in a Unicode-related question might be of help.