# Replacing all instances of string in string Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Right now my output to a file is like:

```
<b>Nov 22Â–24</b>   <b>Nov 29Â–Dec 1</b>    <b>Dec 6Â–8</b> <b>Dec 13Â–15</b>   <b>Dec 20Â–22</b>   <b>Dec 27Â–29</b>   <b>Jan 3Â–5</b> <b>Jan 10Â–12</b>   <b>Jan 17Â–19</b>   <b><i>Jan 17Â–20</i></b>    <b>Jan 24Â–26</b>   <b>Jan 31Â–Feb 2</b>    <b>Feb 7Â–9</b> <b>Feb 14Â–16</b>   <b><i>Feb 14Â–17</i></b>    <b>Feb 21Â–23</b>   <b>Feb 28Â–Mar 2</b>    <b>Mar 7Â–9</b> <b>Mar 14Â–16</b>   <b>Mar 21Â–23</b>   <b>Mar 28Â–30</b>
```

I want to remove all the "Â" and css tags (< b >, < / b >). I tried using the .remove and .replace functions but I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file -- FILE NAME-- on line 70, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

The output above is in a list, which I get from a webcrawling function:

```
def getWeekend(item_url):
    dates = []
    href = item_url[:37]+"page=weekend&" + item_url[37:]
    response = requests.get(href)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")  # or BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
    date= soup.select('table.chart-wide > tr > td > nobr > font > a > b')
    return date
```

I write it to a file like so:

```
for item in listOfDate:
    wr.writerow(item)
```

How can I remove all the tags so that only the date is left?

Comment: what is the page encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got a working solution, but for the future:

1. Use `get_text()` to get rid of the tags

`date = soup.select('table.chart-wide > tr > td > nobr > font > a > b').get_text()`

2. Use `.replace(u'\xc2',u'')` to get rid of the `Â`. the `u` makes `u'\xc2'` a unicode string. (This might take some futzing around with encoding, but for me `get_Text()` is already returning a unicode object.)

(Additionally, possibly consider `.replace(u'\u2013',u'-')` because right now, you have an en-dash :P.)

`date = date.replace(u'\xc2',u'').replace(u'\u2013',u'-')`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think aString.regex_replace('toFind', 'toReplace') should work. Either that or writeb it to a file, and then run sed on it like:  sed -i 's/toFind/toReplace/g'

Comment: Thanks, I'll just use the excel find and replace function, just tried it and its super easy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have an ASCII string from the website.  You need to convert the non-ASCII text into something Python can understand before manipulating it.

Python will use Unicode when given a chance.  There's plenty of information out there if you just have a look.  For example, you can find more help from other questions on this website:

[Python: Converting from ISO-8859-1/latin1 to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539881/python-converting-from-iso-8859-1-latin1-to-utf-8)

[python: unicode in Windows terminal, encoding used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344853/python-unicode-in-windows-terminal-encoding-used)

[What is the difference between encode/decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447107/what-is-the-difference-between-encode-decode)

Answer (score 0):

If your Python 2 source code has literal  non-ASCII characters such as `Â` then you should declare the source code encoding as the error message says. Put at the top of your Python file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Make sure the file is saved using the utf-8 encoding and  use Unicode strings to work with the text.

Comment: If you are a VIm user more than an emacs one, you can instead put near the top: ``# vim:set fileencoding=utf8:``.

Comment: @bufh: Python doesn't care as long as it matches [`"coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)"` regular expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).