# How to change encoding of printed xml data and still strip namespaces?

Tags: python, xml, encoding, namespaces, iterparse

I need to retrieve a lot of information from multiple xml files. I'm trying to make a webscraper, but I have problems with the encoding while still stripping all the namespaces (see code). The content of the xml files is written in danish and contains the special characters "æøå".

**How can I change the file encoding of the printed xml data while still stripping namespaces?**

```
import urllib
from StringIO import StringIO
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import re

url = "http://loremIpsum.co "
xmlString = urllib.urlopen(url).read() #data with namespaces

it = ET.iterparse(StringIO(xmlString))

for _, el in it:
    if '}' in el.tag:
        el.tag = el.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
root = it.root


print root.findtext("loremIpsum/loremIpsum")
```

Current print output if `root.findtext("loremIpsum/loremIpsum")` were the special character "ø":

```
u'\xd8
```

Expected output:

```
ø
```

Comment: You forgot to described your problem. Errors, stack traces, etc...

Comment: it's an encoding error..?    u'\xd8st  !=  Øst

Comment: Thomas -- I know you're new to SO. You should review how to post questions.  Without the stack trace, there is no way to understand the context of the error -- for example, what line number generated the error. Take a few minutes to read the guidance and revise your question.

Comment: I have tried to revise my question again.. I'm not getting any errors, I just need to change the encoding..

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you are describing something that's not an error -- then explain exactly what you expect to see.

Comment: When the content in the xml file contain "æ", "ø" and "å" I expect it to print "æ", "ø" and "å" its not.. As an example it currently printing u'\xd8 instead of ø ... Can you explain how I change the encoding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344853/python-unicode-in-windows-terminal-encoding-used#6349430