# Unicode python Error

Tags: python, unicode

i'm trying to print : Pokémon GO Việt Nam

```
print u"Pokémon GO Việt Nam"
```

and i'm getting :

```
print u"PokÚmon GO Vi?t Nam"
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

i've tried :

```
.encode("utf-8")
.decode("utf-8")
.decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8")
unicode(str.decode("iso-8859-4"))
```

My python version is 2.7.9 , Notepad++ UTF-8 encoding .
with no luck , how can i print it ? and i'm encountering this kind of issues all the time , what's the proper way to debug and get the right encoding ?

Comment: What version of python are you using? I printed this using python 3.5 and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you typing it or are you getting it from a different source? Copying and pasting from SO yields correct results on both 2.7 and 3.5, on my OS.

Comment: Using Python 3+ works with print as a function

Comment: my python version is 2.7.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print "Pokémon GO Việt Nam"
```

You can find [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) more info

For PyCharm settings, go to the menu: PyCharm --> Preference then use the search to look up "encoding", you should reach the following screen:

[image]

Comment: yeah try that also , it work if we just print `u"pokémon"` but not `"Pokémon GO Việt Nam"`

Comment: @BrendaMartinez: what encoding is your editor using?

Comment: @BrendaMartinez make sure that both your IDE encoding as well as the project encoding are set to 'utf-8'

Comment: Utf-8 , notepad++

Comment: @BrendaMartinez well notepad++ is another problem :) use a proper IDE such as PyCharm: you'll get all the benefits of IDE such as debugging and inspection capabilities as well as many other goodies.

Comment: yeah for that i've tested sublimetext and i'm getting `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u1ec7' in position 13: character maps to <undefined>` if i just print "Pokémon" all good , "Việt" what causing the problem .

Comment: @BrendaMartinez  sublime is NOT an IDE - it's the same as Notepad++... You can check the default encoding settings of sublime by going to the menu: sublime text --> Preferences --> Settings - Default and then search for: `default_encoding`

Comment: i've just installed pycharm `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u1ec7' in position 13: character maps to <undefined>` , and i'm using encoding declaration , Pycharm5

Comment: @BrendaMartinez I've added a screenshot of PyCharm preferences - compare it to yours.

Comment: yeah exactly the same , i'm just trying `#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
print u"ệ"` with no luck , the code works for you ?

Comment: Yes, you can see in the screenshot that it does. Maybe there's some encoding issue with your OS ? can you try a different computer in order to eliminate potential causes ?

Comment: thanks for your effort , that was correct , i've test it in my VPS (ubuntu) and worked , Windows is the problem , i'm getting this kind of errors all the time :/

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with Windows: my Win-machine is back at home and I'm at work... Anyways, glad you pinned the issue to the OS. The following might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344853/python-unicode-in-windows-terminal-encoding-used

Answer (score 1):

Specify the encoding

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in the top of the program

Comment: yeah tried that also , it work if we just print u"pokémon" but not "Pokémon GO Việt Nam"

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can encode the unicode string:

```
print u"Pokémon GO Việt Nam".encode('utf-8')
```

The advantage is that the bytes in the resulting string are independent of the encoding of the source file: `u"ệ".encode('utf-8')` is always the same 3 bytes `"\xe1\xbb\x87"`.

It is also consistent with what you'd do if you have an unicode string in a variable.

```
# get text from somewhere...
text = u"Pokémon GO Việt Nam"

# assuming your terminal expects UTF-8 -- this won't work on Windows.
print text.encode('utf-8')
```