# Operate windows tool "diskpart" with the help of python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, diskpart

I am currently trying to write a Python 3 module that can conveniently serve me the Windows internal tool *"diskpart"*.
Now I have the problem that the output of the tool always depends on the system language.

Does anyone know how I can get it to display these umlauts correctly as well?

If I start *"diskpart"* separately in a command line and enter the command there, all umlauts are displayed correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkYHq.png)

Here is the call in my Python source code:

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['diskpart'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

    # Send command to diskpart and read output
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(input=diskpart_command)

    if proc.returncode == 0:
        logger.info(f"Diskpart command executed successfully: {diskpart_command}")
        return stdout
    else:
        error_message = f"Error executing diskpart: {stderr}"
        logger.error(error_message)
        return error_message
```

Here is the current output of my application:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl5HO.png)

Comment: Run everything in utf8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344853/python-unicode-in-windows-terminal-encoding-used

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux i think so....sys.getdefaultencoding() says 'utf-8'