# Why does "Save as UTF-8" in Eclipse fix the Python UnicodeEncodeError?

Tags: python, eclipse, character-encoding

I have:

- a file `file.txt` containing just one character: `♠`, and UTF-8 encoded.
- a CP-1252 encoded Python script `test.py` containing:

  ```
  import codecs
  text = codecs.open('file.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8').read()
  print('text: {0}'.format(text))
  ```

When I run it in Eclipse 4.7.2 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and with Python 3.5.2 x64, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse-4-7-2-workspace\SEtest\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print('text: {0}'.format(text))
  File "C:\programming\python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2660' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>
```

My understanding is that the issue stems from the fact that on Microsoft Windows, by default the Python interpreter uses [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) as its encoding and therefore has is with the character `♠`.

Also, I would note at that point that I kept Eclipse default encoding, which can be seen in `Preferences > General > Workspace`:

[image]

When I change the Python script `test.py`  to:

```
import codecs
print(u'♠') # <--- adding this line is the only modification
text = codecs.open('file.txt', 'r', 'UTF-8').read()
print('text: {0}'.format(text))
```

then try to run it, I get the error message:

[image]

(note: Eclipse is configured to save the script whenever I run it).

After selecting the option `Save as UTF-8`, I get the same error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Francky\eclipse-4-7-2-workspace\SEtest\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(u'\u2660')
  File "C:\programming\python\Python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2660' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

which I think is expected since the Python interpreter still uses [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

But if I run the script again in Eclipse without any modification, it  works. The output is:

```
♠
text: ♠
```

Why does it work?

Comment: Where do you get the output? Do you get the same output in Eclipse in the Console view, and on the command line?

Comment: @howlger All ouputs were obtained in  Eclipse in the Console view.

Comment: @howlger If I run the UTF-8 encoded python script outside Eclipse, in cmd.exe, I get  the same `UnicodeEncodeError` as when I was writing the corresponding CP-1252 in Eclipse.

Comment: And what happens if you try the following on the command line? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18439832/6505250

Comment: @howlger Thanks. Using `cmd /K chcp 65001` does prevent the `UnicodeEncodeError` from happening, but the displayed text isn't pretty: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8TgJ.png

Comment: If opening a new window via `start cmd /K chcp 65001` does not help, maybe you have also [set the source file's encoding via `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (see this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6179672/6505250). Otherwise, I don't know what else to do. To answer your question, why it is working in Eclipse: the encoding for the Console view is set in the run configuration in the tab _Common_ which I guess it set to `UTF-8` in your case.

Comment: @howlger Thanks, adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` didn't help. Where is the the tab Common?

Comment: You will find the _Common_ tab in the run configuration: _Run  > Run Configurations..._ http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html

Comment: @howlger Thank you, you're correct: the encoding indicated in the Common tab changed from CP-1252 to UTF-8.  Why does that change the behavior of the python interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phyton **converts the text to be printed to** the encoding of the console which is **the active code page** on Windows ([at least until version 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0528/)).

To avoid the `UnicodeEncodeError` you have to change the console encoding to UTF-8. There are [several ways](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2014/01/12/python-unicode-console-output.html) to do this, e. g. on the Windows command line by executing `cmd /K chcp 65001`.

In Eclipse, the **encoding** of the console can be set to **`UTF-8`** in the run configuration (***Run > Run Configurations...***), in the ***Common* tab**.

The text file encoding settings in *Window > Preferences: General > Workspace* and in *Project > Properties: Ressource* are only used by text editors how to display text files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: From [UTF-8 in Windows 7 CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22340018/395857): "you need to use Lucida console fonts in addition to executing chcp 65001 from cmd console."