# Python 3.3 - Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python hashlib problem “TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/python-hashlib-problem-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashin)

Here is a code in Python 3 which generates a password with salt:

```
import hmac
import random
import string
import hashlib


def make_salt():
    salt = ""
    for i in range(5):
        salt = salt + random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    return salt


def make_pw_hash(pw, salt = None):
    if (salt == None):
        salt = make_salt() #.encode('utf-8') - not working either
    return hashlib.sha256(pw + salt).hexdigest()+","+ salt


pw = make_pw_hash('123')
print(pw)
```

The error it gives me is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\german\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    pw = make_pw_hash('123')
  File "C:\Users\german\test.py", line 17, in make_pw_hash
    return hashlib.sha256(pw + salt).hexdigest()+","+ salt
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

I'm not allowed to change the algorithm of generating a password, so I only want to fix the error using probably the method `encode('utf-8')` . How can I do it?

Comment: The problem is with `'123'`, which has no encoding.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simply call the method you already mentioned on the `pw` and `salt` strings:

```
pw_bytes = pw.encode('utf-8')
salt_bytes = salt.encode('utf-8')
return hashlib.sha256(pw_bytes + salt_bytes).hexdigest() + "," + salt
```

Comment: Not working. Which one is correct: `return hashlib.sha256(pw.encode('utf-8') + salt.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()+","+ salt` or `return hashlib.sha256((pw + salt).encode('utf-8').hexdigest()+","+ salt`

Comment: @Grienders I would use bytes as early as possible. So encode the pw separately (or expect it as bytes in the first place, `b'123'`) and create the hash as bytes already. So use `string.ascii_letters.encode("latin1")` (or utf8, which has the same result) in `make_pw_hash()`. This doesn't change the algorithm, just the implementation.