# Generate ID from string in Python

Tags: python, hash

I'm struggling a bit to generate ID of type `integer` for given `string` in Python.

I thought the built-it `hash` function is perfect but it appears that the IDs are too long sometimes. It's a problem since I'm limited to 64bits as maximum length.

My code so far: `hash(s) % 10000000000`.
The input string(s) which I can expect will be in range of 12-512 chars long.

Requirements are:

- integers only
- generated from provided string
- ideally up to 10-12 chars long (I'll have ~5 million items only)
- low probability of collision..?

I would be glad if someone can provide any tips / solutions.

Comment: curious, how does this compare to things suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-python?

Comment: why use md5 vs sha3? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601592/safest-way-to-generate-a-unique-hash

Comment: fyi you might need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/how-to-correct-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> m = hashlib.md5()
>>> m.update("some string")
>>> str(int(m.hexdigest(), 16))[0:12]
'120665287271'
```

The idea:

1. Calculate the hash of a string with MD5 (or SHA-1 or ...) in hexadecimal form (see module [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html))
2. Convert the string into an integer and reconvert it to a String with base 10 (there are just digits in the result)
3. Use the first 12 characters of the string.

If characters `a-f` are also okay, I would do `m.hexdigest()[0:12]`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks great! It does not return integer but it just a matter of casting it back to int. Would be nice if we could go away with the int/str/int coerce dance. Any idea? :)

Comment: ``m.hexdigit()`` provides a string with 32 characters. So the maximum value is ``'f'*32`` with 39 digits (=``len(str(int('f'*32,16)))``). So You can divide by 1E17 in the end. With this solution collisions might be more probably... But I did not thought it through...

Comment: ``m.hexdigit()`` provides ``m.digest_size * 2`` characters (this might change, depending on the hash function you want to use)

Comment: Note: you can also use the string [digest()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.digest), slice enough bytes from them and convert it to an integer (better to say: interpreting the byte string as an integer)

Comment: curious, how does this compare to things suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-python?

Comment: why use md5 vs sha3? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601592/safest-way-to-generate-a-unique-hash

Comment: fyi you might need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/how-to-correct-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing

Comment: MD5 is a bit of a sledgehammer to hash a string. Nuclear weapons are a good way to dig a hole, too.

Answer (score 2):

encode utf-8 was needed for mine to work:

```
def unique_name_from_str(string: str, last_idx: int = 12) -> str:
    """
    Generates a unique id name
    refs:
    - md5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974499/generate-id-from-string-in-python
    - sha3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601592/safest-way-to-generate-a-unique-hash
    (- guid/uiid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534839/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)
    """
    import hashlib
    m = hashlib.md5()
    string = string.encode('utf-8')
    m.update(string)
    unqiue_name: str = str(int(m.hexdigest(), 16))[0:last_idx]
    return unqiue_name
```

see my ultimate-utils python library.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed to add extra dependency, you can continue using `hash` function in the following way:

```
>>> my_string = "whatever"
>>> str(hash(my_string))[1:13]
'460440266319'
```

*NB:*

- I am ignoring 1st character as it may be the negative sign.
- `hash` may return different values for same string, as `PYTHONHASHSEED` Value will change everytime you run your program. You may want to set it to some fixed value. [Read here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED)