# Python: Given a group of strings uniformly bucket them into k buckets so that same strings go to the same bucket

Tags: python, hash

I have a set (of 2000) rows with many elements per row. One of the elements in a row is a string ("name") that is common per group of 5 rows (the total number of unique names is 500). 
I want rows with the same "name" to end up in the same bucket. So the function should always return the same value for the given input.

I want to use it for a k-fold cross validation, so I need to create k buckets with numbers of elements as uniformly distributed as possible, +/- few elements is fine but more than 10% is not.

For k = 10 I should have 10 buckets with 200 elements in each, 190 or 210 is ok, but 250 and 180 is not. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974499/generate-id-from-string-in-python?answertab=active#tab-top) but it did not give me a very uniform result. This may be due to a dataset itself but it would be great to have somewhat balanced number of elements per bucket. K is usually either 5 or 10.

An example:

name1, date1_1, location1_1, number1_1

name1, date1_2, location1_2, number1_2
...

name1, date1_5, location1_5, number1_5

name2, date2_1, location2_1, number2_1
...

name2, date2_5, location2_5, number2_5
...

name400, date400_1, location400_1, number400_1
...

name400, date400_5, location400_5, number400_5

Output example:

i,name1, date1_1, location1_1, number1_1

i,name1, date1_2, location1_2, number1_2
...

i,name1, date1_5, location1_5, number1_5

j,name2, date2_1, location2_1, number2_1
...

j,name2, date2_5, location2_5, number2_5
...

k,name400, date400_1, location400_1, number400_1
...

k,name400, date400_5, location400_5, number400_5

where 1 < i, j, k < K   (K = 5 or K = 10)

Comment: do you have 400 names then?

Comment: Question is very unclear. What is intended results, what does data look like, why can you not just partition it cleanly 1-20, 21-40 ad. nasueam? Provide example also please

Comment: Is it possible then to just set some value K to 0, add the first group of names to K=0, then iterate K to 1 ..... until K = 5/10 then loop back to K=0? I assume this is for some ML project as you mentioned cross validation so do you need some form of random sampling designed in?

Comment: I added an example, thank you for the suggestion. Yes, partitioning would be an option but I would rather not assume that the dataset came in already sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a hash-table, yes? In that case just create a dictionary of size K, and devise a hash-function that takes your string as input and comes back with the index. In the example you provided, an appropriate one might be:

```
h = int(name.split(',')[0].strip("name")) % K
```

To be fair, this is pretty naive and doesn't take into account the distribution of your names (you could have many with `name1` and very few with `name400` for example) but if they are more-or-less the same then that method should work reasonably well.

If your names aren't as convenient as that, you could create a secondary table that simply takes in your name and spits out a number. For instance, suppose you had the names: "Bob", "Sally", "Larry", ...

```
nameIndexMappings = {"Bob" : 0, "Sally" : 1, "Larry" : 2}
h = nameIndexMappings[name.split(',')[0]] % K
```

Then you can setup another dictionary like this:

```
rowMapping = dict()
index = 0
for i in range(0, K):
    rowMapping[i] = list()
for row in rows:
    name = row.split(',')[0]
    if (name not in nameIndexMappings):
        nameIndexMappings[index] = name
        index += 1
    h = nameIndexMappings[name] % K
    rowMapping[h].append(row)
```

After doing this, `rowMapping` should contain K lists each with about the same number of elements in them (assuming, of course, that all your names are more-or-less equally distributed).

Comment: The "name1" was just an example, I don't have numbers in the name the way you assumed. Names can be "McDonald's", "Starbucks", "Coffee shop", "any name 123@". So we can assume that names are well distributed, so my concern is not the case @bearrito mentioned where one case/name is very dominant (but I agree that is a valid point in general).

Comment: @hebeha I figured that might be the case. See my updated answer

Comment: If your names are well-distributed can you not compute the hash as the hashcode modulo K?

Comment: You could if you preferred. I think the result would be similar

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for isn't feasible without more constraints.

Imagine if your input consisted of the input string "A" N times,  with N arbitrarily large, and input string "B" only 1 times. What would like the output to be?

In any case what you want to do is solve is  bin-packing optimization problem.