# Python: TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, sha256

I am trying to read in a file of passwords. Then I am trying to compute the hash for each password and compare it to a hash I already have to determine if I have discovered the password. However the error message I keep getting is "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing". Here is my code:

```
from hashlib import sha256

with open('words','r') as f:
    for line in f:

        hashedWord = sha256(line.rstrip()).hexdigest()

        if hashedWord == 'ca52258a43795ab5c89513f9984b8f3d3d0aa61fb7792ecefe8d90010ee39f2':
            print(line + "is one of the words!")
```

Can anyone please help and provide an explanation?

Comment: Which line does the error message refer to?

Comment: this may be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing

Comment: You should probably fix your indents, as people are more willing to help people with code they can cut and paste into their interpreter.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error message means exactly what it says: You have a Unicode string. You can't SHA-256-hash a Unicode string, you can only hash bytes.

But why do you have a Unicode string? Because you're opening a file in text mode, which means you're implicitly asking Python to decode the bytes in that file (using your default encoding) to Unicode. If you want to get the raw bytes, you have to use binary mode.

In other words, just change this line:

```
with open('words','r') as f:
```

… to:

```
with open('words', 'rb') as f:
```

---

You may notice that, once you fix this, the `print` line raises an exception. Why? because you're trying to add a `bytes` to a `str`. You're also missing a space, and you're printing the un-stripped line. You could fix all of those by using two arguments to `print` (as in `print(line.rstrip(), "is one of the words")`).

But then you'll get output like `b'\xc3\x85rhus' is one of the words` when you wanted it to print out `Århus is one of the words`. That's because you now have bytes, not strings. Since Python is no longer decoding for you, you'll need to do that manually. To use the same default encoding that sometimes works when you don't specify an encoding to `open`, just call `decode` without an argument. So:

```
print(line.rstrip().decode(), "is one of the words")
```

Answer (score 22):

If you want read information as unicode string from the file, this code line would work: 
`hashedWord = sha256(line.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()`

Comment: this is the simplest solution