# Convert hashlib.sha256 digest string back to hashlib object

Tags: python

I have a text file with a bunch of sha256 strings -
I want to take `25f2b3c5f25f612a7e380c893473b3b6b6d4f6275feee685aafb3b78ea9bfa20` and turn it back into a hashlib.sha256 object? is that possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539366/python-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing)

Comment: No, because I don't have the starting text. I only have the digest string.

Comment: What do you think this will accomplish?  You can't invert a hash back to the original contents.  That's impossible.  If you're trying to add additional stuff to your hash, you may be able to find a pure Python implementation where you can shove your hash as the current state.

Comment: use deserialization! maybe helpful.

Answer (score 0):

***SHA256***  (Secure Hash Algorithm)
is a one way hash,that means you can't convert the hash back to the original content.
so no it's not possible!