# Python 3 Unicode Objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I use this code for hashing and salt:

```
def make_hash(password):
"""Generate a random salt and return a new hash for the password."""
if isinstance(password, str):
    password = password.encode('utf-8')
salt = b64encode(urandom(SALT_LENGTH))
print (salt, type(salt))
#print (salt.encode('utf-8'), type(salt.encode('utf-8')))
return 'PBKDF2${}${}${}${}'.format(
    HASH_FUNCTION,
    COST_FACTOR,
    salt,
    b64encode(pbkdf2_bin(password, salt, COST_FACTOR, KEY_LENGTH,
                         getattr(hashlib, HASH_FUNCTION))))
```

Here is the pbkdf2_bin:

```
def pbkdf2_bin(data, salt, iterations=1000, keylen=24, hashfunc=None):
"""Returns a binary digest for the PBKDF2 hash algorithm of `data`
with the given `salt`.  It iterates `iterations` time and produces a
key of `keylen` bytes.  By default SHA-1 is used as hash function,
a different hashlib `hashfunc` can be provided.
"""
hashfunc = hashfunc or hashlib.sha1
mac = hmac.new(data, None, hashfunc)
def _pseudorandom(x, mac=mac):
    h = mac.copy()
    h.update(x)
    return map(int, h.digest())
buf = []
for block in range(1, -(-keylen // mac.digest_size) + 1):
    rv = u = _pseudorandom(salt + _pack_int(block))
    for i in range(iterations - 1):
        u = _pseudorandom(''.join(map(chr, u)))
        rv = starmap(xor, zip(rv, u))
    buf.extend(rv)
return ''.join(map(chr, buf))[:keylen]
```

I already adjusted some things as:

I replaced `unicode -> str`

I replaced `izip -> zip`

I changed this `map(ord, h.digest()) -> map(int, h.digest())`

---

For python 2 it works fine. I just jumped into python 3.

I am trying to fix this for 2 hours already, all solutions here do not work for me, probably I am missing something. As far as I understand somewhere I need simply to add `.encode("utf-8")` But I tryed already to put this everywhere. I thought it must be either the `salt` or the `x` in `h.update(x)`

I get the `Unicode Objects must be encoded before hashing` in these lines:

[image]

**EDIT**

I found the line where something happens if I encode, but it results in an other error.

```
u = _pseudorandom(''.join(map(chr, u)).encode("utf-8"))
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing) and see if it helps maybe?

Comment: I saw this aleady, I saw every similar post aswell, it does not work for me.

Comment: That's exactly where I am stumbling now... Did you manage to solve this problem in the meantime?

Comment: @nostradamus Yes I solved this, I will post my code when I am home.

Comment: @Roman: That would be great! In the meantime, I found a workaround by using another module. Anyways I'd be interested in the solution for reasons of curiosity.