# TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, unicode, hash, encode

I was trying to replicating the python program from this website:　http://ecomunsing.com/build-your-own-blockchain．

The Python program is as follows:

```
import hashlib, json
import random

def hashMe(msg=''):
    if type(msg)!=str:
        msg = json.dumps(msg, sort_keys=True) 
    return str(hashlib.sha256(msg).hexdigest(), 'uft-8')

def makeTransaction(maxValue=3):
    sign= int(random.getrandbits(1))*2-1 
    amount = random.randint(1,maxValue)
    alicePays = sign*amount
    bobPays = -1*alicePays
    return {u'Alice':alicePays, u'Bob':bobPays}

txnBuffer = [makeTransaction() for i in range(30)]


def updateState(txn, state):
    state = state.copy() 
    for key in txn:  
        if key in state.key():
            state[key] += txn[key]
        else:
            state[key] = txn[key]
    return state

def isValidTxn(txn, state):
    if sum(txn.values()) is not 0:
        return False    
    for key in txn.keys():
        acctBalance = state[key]
    else:
        acctBalance = 0    
    if (acctBalance + txn[key]) <0:
        return False   
    return True

state = {u'Alice':50, u'Bob':50}
genesisBlockTxns = [state]
genesisBlockContents = {u'blockNumber':0,u'parentHash':None,u'txnCount':1,u'txns':genesisBlockTxns}
genesisHash = hashMe( genesisBlockContents )
```

The error message is

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/simpleexample.py", line 186, in <module>
genesisHash = hashMe( genesisBlockContents )

  File "C:/simpleexample.py", line 45, in hashMe
return str(hashlib.sha256(msg).hexdigest(), 'uft-8')

TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

I am using Python 3.6.0 | Anaconda 4.3.1 (32-bit) in Windows 7. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverlow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance on how to ask questions

Comment: Duplicate of: [TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7585307/55075)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import hashlib

message = 'whatever'.encode()

code = hashlib.sha256(message).hexdigest()

print(code)
```

Answer (score 2):

The message is quite clear: a Unicode object must be encoded using `encode` before you can hash it. What Unicode object is it referring to? The one passed into the hashing function `hashlib.sha256`, i.e. `msg`.

Once you get past that you'll find that the return from `hexdigest()` is already a string that doesn't need `str` applied to it. You spelled `utf-8` incorrectly anyway.

```
return hashlib.sha256(msg.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```