# How to encode Unicode objects in Python?

Tags: python, authentication

I've been trying to find a solution here for my problem for a long time but nothing seems to work. I am trying to authenticate with the Coinbase Pro API in Python but I am getting

"Unicode-Objects must be encoded before hashing" error.

Please see the code below for your reference.

```
import json, hmac, hashlib, time, requests, base64
from requests.auth import AuthBase

# Create custom authentication for Exchange
class CoinbaseExchangeAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key, passphrase):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key
        self.passphrase = passphrase

    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = str(time.time())
        message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)
        signature_b64 = signature.digest().encode('base64').rstrip('\n')

        request.headers.update({
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_b64,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
            'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
        return request

api_url = 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com/'
auth = CoinbaseExchangeAuth(api_key='XXXX',
                            secret_key='XXXX',
                            passphrase='XXXX')

# Get accounts
r = requests.get(api_url + 'accounts', auth=auth)
```

It would be great if someone can point me to the right direction. I couldn't find the correct solution after searching.

Comment: what line triggers the error? Post a trace.

Comment: @t.stv I am actually getting this error now: 

 File "/Users/asanga/Documents/python_projects/coinbasepro/main.py", line 22, in __call__
    hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (85) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Comment: so your secret_key contains some strange stuff. Have you tried to call encode on the secret_key?

Comment: @t.stv I've created a new pair of keys and tried to run the code again but now I am getting the "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" error again

Comment: @t.stv stacetrack below: 

 File "/Users/asanga/Documents/python_projects/coinbasepro/main.py", line 23, in __call__
    signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/hmac.py", line 153, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/hmac.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.update(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/hmac.py", line 102, in  self.inner.update(msg)

Comment: try sectet_key.encode('utf-8') in __init__

Comment: @t.stv still didn't work, I am getting the same error message.

Comment: check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/how-to-correct-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing

Comment: After some further debugging I found that the main problem lies in this line: 

signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I found that the following solution worked for me:

```
def __call__(self, request):
    print(request.body)
    timestamp = str(time.time())
    message = (timestamp + (request.method).upper() + request.path_url + (request.body or ''))
    message = message.encode('UTF-8')
    hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
    signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256).digest()
    signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature)
```

Answer (score 1):

`hashlib` takes **bytes** or **bytearray**. Try this -

```
...
message = message.encode('UTF-8')
hmac_key = self.secret_key.encode('UTF-8')
signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)
```

Comment: @Nant, did you follow this one? https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication

Comment: That's for authenticating to the coinbase wallet not the coinbase pro exchange. I've seen that article but unfortunately that's not quite what I want

Comment: @Nant, updated the solution. Try now :-) hope it helps!

Comment: I am getting this error now: 

File "/Users/asanga/Documents/python_projects/coinbasepro/main.py", line 31, in __call__
    signature_b64 = signature.digest().encode('base64').rstrip('\n')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Well, `hashlib` takes bytes right? and you can achieve it with UTF-8 encoding. Is it necessary to encode in base64???

Comment: I had to change a few things but generally, this worked. Thanks for your help. See my answer for the solution abover.

Comment: Yes, it should work fine as well. Because both converts to bytes, `base64` and `UTF-8` and the `hmac` takes bytes like objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved it, message.encode('utf-8')

```
   def __call__(self, request):
    timestamp = str(time.time())
    message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url +     (request.body or '')
    hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
    signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
    signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())
```