# Can I use a variable when a want pass a string for hash value in python?

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I saw we can pass a string for any kind of hash like this:

```py
import hashlib
print hashlib.sha1('Whatever').hexdigest()
```

But if my string stay at some variable, like that:

```py
import hashlib
test ="teste1234"
m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update(test)
print(m.hexdigest())
```

How can I do that?
The error is "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" or if I only change 'Whatever' for the variable test give me this error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correct TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/how-to-correct-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing)

Comment: Python3. I understand the error message, I want know how can i do right?

Comment: "How can I do that?", put a variable and not a string

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you should pass a binary string to perform the hash, not a Unicode string.
To encode just type the following:

```
import hashlib
test = "teste1234"

m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update(test.encode())

print(m.hexdigest())
# a1a8d617f884f106ccdcc6470c29cbdc4d9f7990
```

References: [hashlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms) and [Unicode string docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str)