# Why am I receiving either a TypeError or Unicode Decode Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a program to hash a list of passwords using SHA1. When the program is run it should create a file with all the passwords hashed. The plaintext password file is saved as UTF-8 and was composed in Notepad. Unfortunately I am receiving a unicode decode error. I tried saving the file as ANSII (the only non-unicode option I currently have) and then I received a TypeError telling me that unicode objects must be encoded before hashing.

```
def read_file(filename):
    '''procedure to open a file and read its contents'''
    #open a file
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    #read the file
    filetext = file.read()
    #close the file
    file.close

#read the file 'passwords.txt'
read_file('passwords.txt')

#convert file contents into a common hash
def hash_text(filename):
    ''' Function takes contents of the file passwords.txt and converts it to
        SHA1, saving result in a new file'''
    #read the passwords.txt file
    read_file('passwords.txt')
    #import hashlib
    import hashlib
    #hash whatever file is input 
    hash_object = hashlib.sha1(filename)
    hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
    print(hex_dig)
    #create a new file to store the hashed passwords in
    hash_store = open("hashwords.txt", "x", "a")
    #write to the file
    hashedtext = hash_store.append()
    #close the file
    hash_store.close

#run the function
hash_text('passwords.txt')
```

Comment: This? [How to correct TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7585307/3890632)

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but to call a function in Python the parantheses are required; `file.close` doesn't do anything (it needs to be `file.close()`, or even better, use a context manager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of problems which I've tried to correct:

```
import hashlib  # imports go on top

def read_file(filename):
    # Use a context manager
    with open(filename, "rb") as file:  # binary mode
        # return a value, so it can be used by the other function
        return file.read()
        # closing no longer necessary

def hash_text(filename):
    """ Function takes contents of the file passwords.txt and converts it to
        SHA1, saving result in a new file"""
    contents = read_file('passwords.txt')  # store the return value in a variable
    hash_object = hashlib.sha1(contents)  # hash the contents, not the name of the file
    hex_dig = hash_object.hexdigest()
    print(hex_dig)
    # create a new file to store the hashed passwords in
    with open("hashwords.txt", "a") as hash_store
        hash_store.write(f"{hex_dig}\n")

# Run the function
hash_text("passwords.txt")
```

If you have several passwords in the file `passwords.txt`, you'll probably want to iterate over lines and hash each line individually, instead of the entire file.