# MD5 Hash Cracker -- Unicode Objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, encoding, hash

I'm struggling to get this script to work. I'm not sure where I need to add the encoding. I receive the error " Unicode objects must be encoded before hashing"

```
import hashlib
import sys
import pybip38 # pip install pybip38
# Note: The pybip38 is limited to Bitcoin (only) BIP38 encoded keys, NOT other alt-coins that use 
BIP38. Probably based on validation performed by that library.

# Example BIP38 Key. Password = test
BIP38 = '6PRSDyF92mGmAqG66BpAfo3sPGrHmkqgkriwQevP82satGzVQjWobYCXxc'

for line in open('passwords.txt'):
passwords = []
password = line.strip()
md5 =  hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
sha512 =  hashlib.sha512(password).hexdigest()
sha256 =  hashlib.sha256(password).hexdigest()
passwords.append(str(password))
passwords.append(str(password) + str(password))
passwords.append(str(md5))
passwords.append(str(md5) + str(md5))
passwords.append(str(sha512))
passwords.append(str(sha512) + str(sha512))
passwords.append(str(sha256))
passwords.append(str(sha256) + str(sha256))

 for item in passwords:
 print "# Trying password: %s" % item
 if pybip38.bip38decrypt(item, BIP38) != False:
 print "\n## KEY FOUND: %s\n" % item
 sys.exit(0)

 print "\n## Password NOT found :-(\n"
```

Comment: Ugh. This is a duplicate, but the duplicate's top-ranked and accepted answers are terrible. Short version: Open the input file in binary mode (`'rb'`), so you get `bytes` from it, not `str`. And don't wrap all the things you're putting in `passwords` with `str`; you *want* them to be `bytes` objects.

Comment: Can you show me what that looks like? I agree, the solutions previously provided don't help much. I have made an edit, but I still get an error. wordlist_file= open ('passwords.txt , "rb)  This is the error                                                                      File "/home/kali/crack-btc-bip38-password/crack-btc-bip38-password.py", line 13, in <module>
    md5 =  hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: There is [a good answer on the dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22644618/364696), it's just (at time of writing) ranked far too low. Use it, and give it an up-vote while you're at it.