# hashlib: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, hashlib

I am running this hashlib code and it runs almost all the way:

```
def generate_hashes(peaks, fan_value=DEFAULT_FAN_VALUE):
if PEAK_SORT:
  sorted(peaks,key=itemgetter(1))

# bruteforce all peaks
peaks=list(peaks)
len_peaks=len(peaks)
for i in range(len_peaks):
  for j in range(1, fan_value):
    if (i + j) < len(peaks):

      # take current & next peak frequency value
      freq1 = peaks[i][IDX_FREQ_I]
      freq2 = peaks[i + j][IDX_FREQ_I]

      # take current & next -peak time offset
      t1 = peaks[i][IDX_TIME_J]
      t2 = peaks[i + j][IDX_TIME_J]

      # get diff of time offsets
      t_delta = t2 - t1

      # check if delta is between min & max
      if t_delta >= MIN_HASH_TIME_DELTA and t_delta <= MAX_HASH_TIME_DELTA:
        h = hashlib.sha1(("%s|%s|%s") % (str(freq1), str(freq2), str(t_delta)))
        yield (h.hexdigest()[0:FINGERPRINT_REDUCTION], t1)
```

However, it returns this error:

```
 h = hashlib.sha1(("%s|%s|%s") % (str(freq1), str(freq2), str(t_delta)))
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

I am honestly completely lost and don't know how to fix it. If you guys have any follow up questions regarding details about the code I will try my best to answer. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correct TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/how-to-correct-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing)

Comment: You may want `h = hashlib.sha1((("%s|%s|%s") % (str(freq1), str(freq2), str(t_delta))).encode())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error message: use `encode` on your text string before hashing.

```
h = hashlib.sha1(("%s|%s|%s" % (str(freq1), str(freq2), str(t_delta))).encode('utf-8'))
```

The reason this is necessary is because `hashlib.sha1()` requires a `bytes` object due to the way it works internally.  Normal Python strings (since version 3.0) are made of Unicode codepoints, which don't fit into a byte.  They need an *encoding* which defines how the translation between codepoints and bytes occurs.  UTF-8 is the most popular encoding, because it can handle every Unicode codepoint yet remain backwards compatible with older encodings like ASCII.

Comment: Just to expand on this answer a bit... hashlib.sha1() takes a `bytes` object not a string, so you have to convert your Unicode string into one, for example by utf-8 encoding it as shown here.

Comment: @eemz thanks for adding that.  You caught me, my answer was a little too terse.  If you don't mind I'm going to copy your comment and expand on it in my answer.