# 'TypeError at /api/chunked_upload/ Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing' errorwhen using botocore in Django project

Tags: django, amazon-s3, botocore

I have hit a dead end with this problem. My code works perfectly in development but when I deploy my project and configure DigitalOcean Spaces & S3 bucket I get the following error when uploading media:

**TypeError at /api/chunked_upload/
Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing**

I'm using django-chucked-uploads and it doesn't play well with Botocore
I'm using Python 3.7

My code is taken from this demo: https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload-demo

Any help will be massively helpful

Answer (score 1):

This library was implemented for Python 2, so there might be a couple of things that don't work out of the box with Python 3.

This issue that you're facing is one of them since files in Python 3 are read directly as Unicode (since now py3's `str` is py2's `unicode`). The `md5` hashing is the part of the code triggering this exception ([this line](https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload/blob/master/chunked_upload/models.py#L48)) because it doesn't expect Unicode strings.

If you have created your own model inheriting from `AbstractChunkedUpload`, you can override the `md5` property to encode the `chunk`s before updating the hash. See this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/how-to-correct-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing) on how to solve this specific.

Hopefully this helped!

**Disclaimer:** I'm the creator of this library. However, I haven't maintained it in a long time to the point that it might be no longer usable.