# Python Django s3 error "file must be encoded before hashing"

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

We send a file via API.

When the file is saved locally or on the same ec2 instance, all works fine, and we get the response from the API

When the file is saved on AWS s3, we get the error 'Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing'

This is the code that works to open and send file from local device but not when getting the file from s3

```
 my_file = self.original_file.open(mode='rb').read()
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal *reproducible* example!

Comment: try this:
```my_file = self.original_file.open(mode='rb',encoding='utf-8').read()```

Comment: @SharimIqbal Thank you but it did not work because self.orfiginal_file is a Django File Field

Comment: You can check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/how-to-correct-typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing

Comment: Thank you again! @SharimIqbal, I did, and it helped a bit but no idea why I need  to add  .encode() when the file is on s3 and I do not need to do so if it's on ec2 or on the local machine