# Python throws UnicodeEncodeError although I am doing str.decode(). Why?

Tags: python, string, encoding, escaping

Consider this function:

```
def escape(text):
    print repr(text)
    escaped_chars = []
    for c in text:
        try:
            c = c.decode('ascii')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            c = '&{};'.format(htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name[ord(c)])
        escaped_chars.append(c)
    return ''.join(escaped_chars)
```

It should escape all non ascii characters by the corresponding htmlentitydefs. Unfortunately python throws

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

when the variable `text` contains the string whose `repr()` is `u'Tam\xe1s Horv\xe1th'`.

But, I don't use `str.encode()`. I only use `str.decode()`. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has two types of strings: character-strings (the `unicode` type) and byte-strings (the `str` type).  The code you have pasted operates on byte-strings.  You need a similar function to handle character-strings.

Maybe this:

```
def uescape(text):
    print repr(text)
    escaped_chars = []
    for c in text:
        if (ord(c) < 32) or (ord(c) > 126):
            c = '&{};'.format(htmlentitydefs.codepoint2name[ord(c)])
        escaped_chars.append(c)
    return ''.join(escaped_chars)
```

I do wonder whether either function is truly necessary for you.  If it were me, I would choose UTF-8 as the character encoding for the result document, process the document in character-string form (without worrying about entities), and perform a `content.encode('UTF-8')` as the final step before delivering it to the client.  Depending on the web framework of choice, you may even be able to deliver character-strings directly to the API and have it figure out how to set the encoding.

Answer (score 11):

It's a misleading error-report which comes from the way python handles the de/encoding process. You tried to decode an already decoded String a second time and that confuses the Python function which retaliates by confusing you in turn! ;-) The encoding/decoding process takes place as far as i know, by the codecs-module. And somewhere there lies the origin for this misleading Exception messages.

You may check for yourself: either

```
u'\x80'.encode('ascii')
```

or

```
u'\x80'.decode('ascii')
```

will throw a Unicode**Encode**Error, where a

```
u'\x80'.encode('utf8')
```

will not, but

```
u'\x80'.decode('utf8')
```

again will!

I guess you are confused by the meaning of encoding and decoding.
To put it simple:

```
                     decode             encode    
ByteString (ascii)  --------> UNICODE  --------->  ByteString (utf8)
            codec                                              codec
```

But why is there a `codec`-argument for the `decode` method? Well, the underlying function can not guess which codec the ByteString was encoded with, so as a hint it takes `codec` as an argument. If not provided it assumes you mean the `sys.getdefaultencoding()` to be implicitly used.

so when you use `c.decode('ascii')` you a) have a (encoded) ByteString (thats why you use decode) b) you want to get a unicode-representation-object (thats what you use decode for) and c) the codec in which the ByteString is encoded is ascii.

See also:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/370199/1107807
    http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html
    http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#utf-8
    http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/python-unicode-and-unicodedecodeerror

Answer (score 5):

You're passing a string that's already unicode. So, before Python can call `decode` on it, it has to actually encode it - and it does so by default using the ASCII encoding.

**Edit to add** It depends on what you want to do. If you simply want to convert a unicode string with non-ASCII characters into an HTML-encoded representation, you can do it in one call: `text.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')`.

Comment: Or is my approach of escaping the characters nonsense?

Answer (score 2):

This answer always works for me when I have this problem:

```
def byteify(input):
    '''
    Removes unicode encodings from the given input string.
    '''
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {byteify(key):byteify(value) for key,value in input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [byteify(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input
```

from [How to get string objects instead of Unicode ones from JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-ones-from-json-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in [this-site](https://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/ascii-codec-cant-encode-character/)

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("latin-1")

a = u'\xe1'
print str(a) # no exception
```

Answer (score -1):

`decode` a `str` make no sense.

I think you can check `ord(c)>127`