# ast.literal_eval somehow throwing UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

OK so...

- a Unicode string gets encoded to a Python 2.x string (actually, a sequence of bytes)
- a Python 2.x string gets decoded to a Unicode string

[Python UnicodeDecodeError - Am I misunderstanding encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368805/python-unicodedecodeerror-am-i-misunderstanding-encode)

I've got this python 2.7 code

```
try:
    print '***'
    print type(relationsline)
    relationsline = relationsline.decode("ascii", "ignore")
    print type(relationsline)
    relationsline = relationsline.encode("ascii", "ignore")
    print type(relationsline)
    relations = ast.literal_eval(relationsline)
except ValueError:
    return
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    return
```

The last line in the code above sometimes throws

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position
>   341: ordinal not in range(128)

I would think that this would (1) start with a string with some (unknown) encoding (2) decode it into a unicode type, representing a string of characters the unicode character set with ascii encodings while ignoring all characters that can't be encoded with ascii (3) encode the unicode type into a string with ascii encoding, ignoring all of the characters that can't be represented in ascii.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "outputprocessor.py", line 69, in <module>
    getPersonRelations(lines, fname)
  File "outputprocessor.py", line 41, in getPersonRelations
    relations = ast.literal_eval(relationsline)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 341: ordinal not in range(128)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But that is clearly wrong somewhere. Even more perplexing is that the UnicodeDecodeError is not catching the UnicodeDecodeError. What am I missing? Maybe this is the problem? http://bugs.python.org/issue22221

Comment: your ascii text isn't. strict ascii is a 7bit charset (0x00 -> 0x7F), and you've got a char that's > 0x7F, which means it's not ascii. maybe it's extended ascii, iso8859-1, or whatever. but it's not "ascii".

Comment: This'll be easier to debug if you can figure out an example that consistently throws the error. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be recommended: a minimal, standalone code sample that runs and produces the error you're talking about when you run it.

Comment: Also, please show us the exception's complete stack trace.

Comment: It is an ast syntax  error I imagine

Answer (score 1):

Look at the stack trace closer.  It is throwing a `SyntaxError`.

You are trying to `literal_eval` the string `"UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 341: ordinal not in range(128)"`.  You can encode/decode that string all you want, but `ast` won't know what to do with it - that's clearly not a valid python literal.

See:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('''UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 341: ordinal not in range(128)''')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 341: ordinal not in range(128)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I would look at the source of whatever is passing these strings to your function, it's generating some bogus input.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `literal_eval` the traceback from  `relationsline = relationsline.encode("ascii", "ignore")` from the passed in string.

You will need to move your `literal_eval` check into its own `try/except` or catch the exception in your original try block or filter the input somehow.

Comment: Huh?  Where in his code does he assign the traceback to `relationsline`?  That's not how exceptions work...

Comment: @roippi, I meant from the string passed in.